# rjags not loading properly

Tags: r, macos, osx-elcapitan

I'm using R 3.3.1 on Mac OSX El Capitan (although, I'm running RStudio on mac.binary.mavericks), and I am unable to properly download 'rjags'. I found [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422355/installing-rjags-in-r-on-osx-mavericks), and I initially tried trouble-shooting the problem by following the quasi-answers given because my error was the same as the initial poster's. I've tried all the methods, but the closest thing that worked is by  directly downloading rjags from CRAN via `install.packages("rjags")`. However, I now have a new error when I run `library("rjags")`:

```
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rjags/R/rjags.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’
```

I'm unsure how to proceed with this error. Can someone help me interpret what this means, and perhaps another means for downloading `rjags` onto my Mac?

EDIT: `sessionInfo()` is as follows:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)  
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] coda_0.18-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1     grid_3.3.1      lattice_0.20-34
```

Comment: I dont have a mac, so this may not be helpful, but I have generally found it easier installing rjags on the command line. On ubuntu i'd use `sudo apt-get install jags ; wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rjags_4-6.tar.gz ; 
sudo R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-jags-include=/usr/local/include/JAGS --with-jags-lib=/usr/local/lib --enable-rpath' rjags_4-6.tar.gz` . The first two lines download jags and rjags, the third installs rjags, where you need to point to where the jags include and lib are. It may be something similar on a mac.

Comment: it's best to post your full sessionInfo() for questions like these

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! I tried using your code, but it's not working. Although, that could be because (a) I'm horrible at coding aside from R, and (b) the code doesn't work on Mac. @user2957945

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I've edited my question to include the sessionInfo().

Comment: @Tula; yes you dont want to use that code exactly. You need to find where the jags include and lib folders are on your system, and alter the paths accordingly.